# repeatable form field type - drag & drop

Tags: module, custom-module

Is it possible to add a drag & drop function for sorting inside a repeatable field? I use repeatable fields in my modules and it would be nice to change the order per drag & drop.

Comment: are you referring to [repeatable](https://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type) fields or [subform fields](https://docs.joomla.org/Repeatable_form_field_type)? If the former, then I'd suggest you don't start using it, as it will be removed in Joomla 4

Comment: As @Lodder mentioned, repeatable fields is deprecated, you should use [subform field](https://docs.joomla.org/Subform_form_field_type) and, yes subform supports drag and drop ordering